# Display video list from specified folder

Tags: java, android

I have tried following code to display video thumbnails in activity from specified folder. The problem is when i debug the app it shows all video paths there but it does not display these.Any suggestions please where i am doing wrong?

**Code**

```
private void init_phone_video_grid() {
    System.gc();
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Funtube/UserData/Videos/" + File.separator);
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
        for (File f: list) {
         String name = f.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(".mp4"))
                count++;
            path = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name;
        }

     videocursor = managedQuery(Uri.parse(path), proj, null, null, null);

     //videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
        count = videocursor.getCount();
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
    }
```

**VideoAdapter**

```
public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context vContext;

        public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
            vContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();
            ViewHolder holder;
            String id = null;
            convertView = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(vContext).inflate(
                        R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                holder.txtSize = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtSize);
                holder.thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

                video_column_index = videocursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                video_column_index = videocursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                // id += " Size(KB):" +
                // videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                holder.txtTitle.setText(id);
                holder.txtSize.setText(" Size(KB):"
                        + videocursor.getString(video_column_index));

                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
                        new String[] { id }, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                long ids = cursor.getLong(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

                ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                        options);
                holder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
                curThumb = null;

            } /*
             * else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             */
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also show `VideoAdapter ` class code

Comment: `VideoAdapter` works correct when i use the commented query.I have updated my question

Comment: means getting `0` in `count = videocursor.getCount();` line?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no count=3 as i have three videos in specified folder but cursor is null. I think i have some problem with query.

Comment: try to pass `file.getAbsolutePath()` instead of `path `  in `Uri.parse`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK still no results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98842/discussion-between--k-and-tabia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Display video list from specified folder

Use `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` with `like` from which directory want to get all mp4 file as:

```
videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
              proj,
              MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ",
              new String[] {"%"+file.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"%"}, null);
```

Comment: It says to convert this in string format `file.getAbsolutePath`